# How to convert real to float without adding extra digits

Tags: sql-server

I have table with real column, i need to multiple all row with billion , this give me good result(151112000):

```
declare @tbl table (n real)
insert into @tbl values(151.112)
select cast (n * 1000000 as float) AS [Quantity1]
from @tbl
```

But when i select from old existing table, `151.112` became to `151112048`.

How it can be?

My old ddl table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProvidentSegmentPortfolioMonthlyHistory](
    [Fund_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Report_Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Segment_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Quantity] [real] NULL,
    [QuantityPercent] [real] NULL,
    [Date_Update] [datetime] NULL,
    [operator] [varchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ProvidentSegmentPortfolioMonthlyHistory ] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Fund_id] ASC,
    [Report_Date] ASC,
    [Segment_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: Can you add the old table DDL?

Comment: I'd say we need more than DDL, we need enough information to reproduce the issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples

Comment: I understand that is floating point issue, but i don't understand why it is different from oldest table.

Comment: and how to resolve it.

Comment: You showed a code sample that *does not* demonstrate the problem you're actually having. Give us a code sample that *does* demonstrate the problem you're actually having.

Comment: Now we have some ddl. Can you share some data where this issue is repeatable? I can't reproduce what you claim is happening.

Comment: I also tried to reproduce  it without success. i deal with existing table.

Answer (score 2):

> I understand that is floating point issue, but i don't understand why
>   it is different from oldest table.

It's different because you think the old table has a value of 151.112 in it, but it doesn't.   It has a value of 151.112048 in it, which it displays as 151.112 because of floating data point inaccuracy.

How to resolve it is to use Decimal instead of Real in your table.

Comment: You would need to give us enough information to reproduce the issue for me to comment further.

Comment: Can you give me example of how 151.112048 became to 151.112?